# Rails ignores ruby installed by rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, operating-system, rbenv

I am using ruby 2.7.6 for my project. On my laptop (KDE Neon) it was installed via rbenv and was working correctly.
After KDE was updated today I started getting

> Your Ruby version is 3.0.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6

To fix that I tried reinstalling both rbenv and ruby that comes with Ubuntu. Also tried `rbenv rehash` with no results. So far rbenv installs ruby correctly and correct vesion is displayed when I do `ruby -v` or `bundle install` in project folder but trying to run `rails s` gives me an error

> Your Ruby version is 3.0.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6

rbenv is installed into `/home/some_user/.rbenv/`

`$PATH` shows

`bash: /home/some_user/.rbenv/shims:/home/some_user/.rbenv/shims:/home/some_user/.rbenv/bin:/home/some_user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin` which I am not sure is correct.

Comment: when in your project use `rbenv local 2.7.6` and then try again

Comment: @LinFelix rbenv local is set and shows 2.7.6 - error is exactly system showing I am using 2.7.6 and than failing with message that I am using 3.0.2

Comment: I have tried it on all projects currently on my computer and it looks like it`s sytemwide.

Comment: What is the output of `which rails` in the terminal?

Comment: @MathieuLeTiec ```/usr/bin/rails```

Comment: @MathieuLeTiec it was great tip
had to run ```gem install rails```, restart terminal and now it`s running correctly

Comment: @MathieuLeTiec it resets after systme restart and I have to install gem again

Answer (score 2):

You're not running the correct rails executable. Try prefixing your rails command with `bundle exec`, for example if you want to run the dev server, type `bundle exec rails s` instead of `rails s`.